# Assembly code that returns the integers of a number in opposite order

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

```
global main
section .data
n db 123
c db '5'

section .text


afisc:
mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,c
mov rdx,1
syscall
ret

afisnr:
mov al,[n]
mov ah,0
mov r8b,10
div r8b
add ah,'0'
mov [c],ah
call afisc
mov[n],al
cmp ah,0
ja afisnr
ret

main:
xor rax,rax
call afisnr



mov rax,60
mov rdi,0
syscall
```

I have this assembly code, and for the number 123 it should return 321 essentially the digits of the number, but instead it just prints the number 1 endless amounts of times. I can't seem to see where I made a mistake.

I don't really know who i should fix it.

Comment: `afisc` changes `rax` which of course includes `al` and `ah`. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: You could store into a buffer and make one `write` system call, with `length = end_ptr - start_ptr`.  A 1-byte number takes at most 3 bytes, so you can reserve stack space for it.